# setText() not displaying anything

Tags: php, android, json

The **setText()** is not displaying any data into my text fields.
I also tried displaying just text like this : `nameView.setText("temp");` but this didn't work either. 
So, I am pasting my code below that fetches data from a PHP script and receives a JSON response. Also, I did check, I am getting the JSON response.
Plus, I have already added the **INTERNET** permission in the **manifest.xml** file

java file :

```
package com.example.shreyastripathy.fetchtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView nameView;
TextView ageView;
TextView jobView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults(); //STRICT MODE ENABLED

    nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nametxt);
    ageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.agetxt);
    jobView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobtxt);

    getData();
}

public void getData(){
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.5.240/work/test.php"); // PHP SCRIPT ADDRESS
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        nameView.setText("Couldn't connect to database");
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
        assert isr != null;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try {
        String n = "";
        String a="";
        String j="";

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            n = n + "Name : "+json.getString("FirstName")+" "+json.getString("LastName")+"\n";
            a= a + "Age : "+json.getInt("Age")+"\n";
            j= j + "Job : "+json.getString("Job")+"\n";
        }

        nameView.setText(n);
        ageView.setText(a);
        jobView.setText(j);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
    }

}
```

}

xml file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/background">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nametxt"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/agetxt"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jobtxt"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What do I do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: may be color background issue, use **android:textColor="#000000"** in xml of your textView if background color is not black

Comment: @AndroidGeek - Device logs or ADB logs ?

Comment: @RahulSharma - No that's not the issue. I checked

Comment: you are using loop, so it is getting jArray last "FirstName" and "LastName" value may be that is blank..also replace "\n" by ""

Comment: @Kat-hat - How do I fix the loop then ?

Comment: Can you please paste the json format that you are getting

Comment: @Kat-hat - `[{"FirstName":"Shreyas","LastName":"Tripathy","Age":"21","Mobile":"123456789"}]`

Comment: please add log inside loop to check the value..use
Log.e("Position==",""+i+" value=== "+n);

Comment: it showing me error in json format .please check the format first

Comment: Add logcat pls ! it seems setText doesnt call at all

Comment: add adb logcat, also HTTP communication is not allowed in main thread, use AsyncTask instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for help. I finally figured out what the problem in the code was. 
The **Column name** that I was fetching from the database entered here was wrong. Merely a typo.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should run getData() in thread.

```
new Thread(){
    public void run() {
        getData();
   };
}.start();`
```

You also check textColor. Maybe text color is same background color.

Comment: Nope ... that didn't work either. Plus, the textColor is fine, I've already checked that

Comment: I checked your code, but link: http://192.168.5.240/work/test.php don't respone any result.